# Why should simple past be used here?

Tags: past-simple, comparison

[Source](http://www.abc.net.au/austory/content/2012/s3712621.htm)

> And he took control of the wine list and ordered a bottle of wine that was more than (what) I earned in a week.

I feel that it latter part should be like

> That was more than what I was earning in a week.
>
> That was more than what I used to earn in a week.

Why should the person go with simple past in the first sentence?

Comment: Colin's point about "how the speaker is choosing to regard the event" is central. The simple past can refer to the then prevailing state or condition, for example, "more than what I earned in a week *back then*".  The continuous **was earning** would emphasize the recurrent weekly paycheck or the week of work itself, its duration rather than its recurrence.  **used to earn** would imply that the weekly salary in the present is not the same as it was in the past (which may or may  not be true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three are good.

As is often the case in questions of aspect in English, different answers are all possible, the difference being in how the speaker is choosing to regard the event, not in the event itself. By saying "I earned in a week", the speaker is implicitly choosing one event of earning, whereas your alternatives consider the regular or continuing process of earning.